# Using Python with Selenium and PhantomJS change screen resolution?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm running headless ubuntu server where I have some web scraper running but I have one big issue with PhantomJS. The `browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)`does nothing... if I print:

```
print(browser.execute_script('return window.screen.width'))
print(browser.execute_script('return window.screen.height'))
```

Without fail no matter what I do, I get only 1024x768 this must be hardcoded or something. I have even tried to use fake "monitor" via xserver-xorg-video-dummy on OS level, or pyvirtualdisplay and xvfb with no luck... its always 1024x768, and i'm getting crazy from it :D ( it print my normal resolution if I run that on normal windows machine )